# Eclipse fxml how to show import requirement

Tags: javafx, autocomplete, fxml

Is there a way to have Eclipse show error when an import is missing for fxml code to work? I just got started with fxml and had a couple of runtime exceptions because I was missing some imports but there weren't any warnings before I compiled.

Comment: FXML files are not compiled. You need to repackage the jar/overwrite the old fxml in the classpath at worst...

Comment: I would recommend you SceneBilder which was made for creating fxml files with a drag-and-drop supporting UI. @xandy